How do you change the channel of your wireless interface via CLI?
I am trying to manually change the channel of my M1 Macbook Air's wifi interface en0 from the command line. I understand this was previously possible using the airport CLI utility, but that's now deprecated. Using it produces the following message:

WARNING: The airport command line tool is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
For diagnosing Wi-Fi related issues, use the Wireless Diagnostics app or wdutil command line tool.

Examination of the sparse wdutil man page reveals no obvious way to do this, and as far as I can tell, Wireless Diagnostics is a GUI only tool.

The AP you are connecting to controls the channel.  Are there two different AP nearby on two different channels?

@MarcWilson I'm trying to make my WiFi interface listen on a specific channel for wardriving.
